# Display first few characters of first few lines of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, text

On Linux in a bash shell, I have a text file with long lines and would like to look at the first few characters of the the first few lines.  Thus, I need something like `head`, but with the ability to limit the number of characters printed per line.

What would the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat /etc/passwd| cut -b -6` will give you the first 6 characters of each line of /etc/passwd file

You may add a  `| head -9` to read only the first nine lines.

Comment: I actually went for ```head file_with_long_lines.txt | cut -c -80```, so characters rather than bytes.